# How can I check if someone is replying to a message from someone specific

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am using Discord.js v13

My goal is in a message event, like this:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
   //Code comes here
})
```

to check if anyone, no matter who, is replying to any message from a specific person

Answer (score 0):

Using the `reference` field, you can get whether the message is a reply.
For example

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
   if (message.reference.messageId) { // the message is a reply to another message
        let referenceMessage = message.channel.messages.cache.get(message.reference.messageId);
        if (referenceMessage.author.id == MY_USER_SNOWFLAKE) {
            // The reply was to the specific user!
        }
   }
})
```

Keep in mind that the reference message must be cached. If it isn't cached, you can use `message.fetchReference()`.

Comment: That means, if I understand correctly, it should look like this:
```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.reference.messageId) { // the message is a reply to another message
        let referenceMessage = message.channel.messages.cache.get(message.reference.messageId);
        if (referenceMessage.author.id == '913720972828352564') {
            message.channel.send('Test Completid')
        }
    }
})
```
And if I understood it correctly, then that only works for a specific message?

Comment: Works for any message that is a reply to any message of a specific author.